# MDX Not equal basic question

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm a BI starter with SSAS and SSRS and I have a very basic question of MDX.

It is very easy to get all values that match a condition in a calculated member. For example

```
WITH MEMBER [MEASURES].TOTAL_DOT_TEST
 AS
(
[Dim Transportation Incident Dot Classification].[Dim Transportation Incident Dot     Classification].&[3],
[Measures].[Fact Transportation Incident Count] 
)
```

will get the number of transportation incidents that have a classification value of 3.

However, using this example, how do I get the number of transportation incidents that does not have an ID of 3?

Something like 
select *
from table
where classification <> 3

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Aggregate](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Aggregate.html)() and [Except](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Except.html)() as following :

```
WITH MEMBER [MEASURES].TOTAL_DOT_TEST
 AS Aggregate (   
      Except( 
        [Dim Transportation Incident Dot Classification].[Dim Transportation Incident Dot     Classification].members ,
        { [Dim Transportation Incident Dot Classification].[Dim Transportation Incident Dot     Classification].&[3] }
      ),
      [Measures].[Fact Transportation Incident Count] 
)
```